# Issue with selecting level form Level Selection screen (Cocos2d + box2d)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

having menu item in level selection screen and depending on selected item level is started ... here is code..where selectedLevel is index of menuItem.

```
if(selectedLevel==0) 
{   
activeScene = [level2_1Scene node]; 
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:activeScene]; 
    } 
else if(selectedLevel==1) 
{   
activeScene = [level2_2Scene node]; 
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:activeScene]; 
    } 
else if(selectedLevel==2) 
{    
activeScene = [level2_3Scene node]; 
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:activeScene];
```

... so on for all level

how can i do it with simple format of level scene name something like this which is not working

```
activeScene = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"level2_%d",selectedLevel+1] node]; 
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:activeScene];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me,,,

```
    NSString *level=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"level2_%dScene",selectedLevel+1];   
    Class sceneClass = NSClassFromString(level);
    activeScene = (bunnyScene*)[sceneClass node] ;
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:activeScene];
```

Answer (score 2):

this snippet from one of my factories can probably do your trick after adaptation:

```
Skill *skkk = (Skill *) NSClassFromString(className);

if (skkk) {
    return (Skill *) [[skkk class] skillWithSpec:ss];
} else {
    MPLOGERROR(@"*****************************************************************");
    MPLOGERROR(@"             no class with name %@", className);
    MPLOGERROR(@"*****************************************************************");
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you are looking for:

```
switch(selectedLevel)
{
    case 0:
    activeScene = [level2_1Scene node];
    break;

    case 1:
    activeScene = [level2_2Scene node];
    break;

    // Etc....
}

if(activeScene) {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:activeScene];
}
```